# Matlab Regexp Extract Values

Tags: regex, matlab, extract

I would like to extract values using Matlab regexp from the patterns  `<value>2021</value>` ,  `<ns1:value>3049</ns1:value>` ,  `<ns2:value>9902</ns2:value>`  (I want 2021, 3049, 9902 as my output).

In general, I am looking for the number between `<value>`  and `</value>`  or between  `<ns(some one-digit number 0-9): value>`  and  `</ns(some one-digit number 0-9): value>` .

My logic is to consider two cases 1) value | 2) ns[0-9]:value, so my code is

```
regexp(data, '((?<=<\((ns[0-9]:)|v)*value>)\w+(?=<\/\((ns[0-9]:)|v)*value>))','match')
```

but it did not work.

Does anybody know how to do this? Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much!

Note that I have successfully used `regexp(data, '((?<=<\w*:*value>)\w+(?=<\/\w*:*value>))','match')` to extract the values, but I would like something more specific to make the code more efficient (I need to scrape thousands of files).

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using lookarounds, you can use 2 capture groups with a backreference to match the `ns` with a single digit part.

- `<` Match opening bracket
- `((?:ns\d:)?)` Capture **group 1**, optionally match `ns` followed by a single digit and `:`
- `value>` Match literally
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits
- `</\1value>` Match `<` followed by a back reference `\1` to what is matched in group 1 and then match *value>*

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6NBl2w/1).